# How to create a messagebox as an argument to powershell.exe?

Tags: powershell

How can I provide arguments to powershell.exe in order to spawn a message box? The key phrase here is arguments to powershell.exe, not from within a .ps1 script and also not from within the Powershell prompt itself. I currently have this but it is producing errors:

```
powershell.exe -Command "[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms"); [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Test!!!")"
```

I have also tried without `-Command` and with `Invoke-Expression`, with and without double quotes surrounding.

Errors created:

```
At line:1 char:51
+ [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(System.Windows.Form ...
+                                                   ~
Missing ')' in method call.
At line:1 char:51
+ ... eflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(System.Windows.Forms); [Syst ...
+                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'System.Windows.Forms' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:71
+ ... flection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(System.Windows.Forms); [Syste ...
+                                                                 ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:114
+ ... stem.Windows.Forms); [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(Test!!!)
+                                                                  ~
Missing ')' in method call.
At line:1 char:114
+ ... stem.Windows.Forms); [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(Test!!!)
+                                                                  ~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'Test!!!' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:121
+ ... stem.Windows.Forms); [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(Test!!!)
+                                                                         ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInMethodCall
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quotation problem. Using the same double quote `"` in both argument and its contents messes up the content. As a work-around, use single quotes within the Powershell command and double quotes around the whole `-Command` parameter. Like so,

```
powershell.exe -Command "[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms'); [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Test!!!')"
```

That being said, `Add-Type -AssemblyName` is IMAO prettier way to load assemblies. Like so,

```
powershell.exe -Command "add-type -assemblyname System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Test!!!')"
```

Comment: Triple all inner double quotes if  you **need to insist upon double quotes** e.g. as in `powershell.exe -Command "… [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("""Test!!! $PSUICulture""")"`.